# Laravel Upload 100 Images to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: php, laravel

I have an e-commerce website and some of the products have 100 images.

if the count of images more than 20 images,  it uploads the first 20 images only!

please advice.

here you are the upload code.

```
    if($request->file('product_image')){
        foreach($request->file('product_image') as $image)
        {

            $filename = $this->millitime().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path().'/backend_assets/uploaded_files/products/'.$filename;
            Image::make($image)->save($location);
            $s3_filePath = 'images/product-images/'. $filename;
            Storage::disk('s3')->put($s3_filePath, file_get_contents($location)); 
            ProductImages::create([
                'product_id'=> $product->id,
                'product_name' => $product->name_english,
                'image' => $filename
            ]);

            if(File::exists($location)) {
                File::delete($location);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not relevant with Laravel. Please change max_file_uploads

in php.ini

```
max_file_uploads=100
```

Comment: Thank you omar.
you are correct.
I don't know how I missed thinking of this.